# The right fuse (inrush current problem )?

Tags: fuses, inrush-current

Hello Electrical Engineers, just a quick question I need to get a fuse between the mains voltage (120V) and the adapter. I know that the load will draw around 30mA and has an operating voltage of 24V.

I was thinking myself:

If the output current after the adapter (gst60a24-p1j, 60W laptop adapter) is 30 mA and 24 Vdc and the input is $$120 V_{ac}$$ the input current would be $$6*10^{-3} A $$ or 6 mA with an efficiency of 90,5% that would be $$6.57*10^{-3} A $$ or 6.57 mA . There are other factors, however: the low efficiency with this small current for this large charger and the biggest problem; the inrush current. The inrush current is stated at 35 A for this adapter. The fuse which I would like to pick a 4 A fuse (SIBA 7008913.1.25), has an $$I^2t = 16 A^2s$$
I don't know how to process this information to know if the fuse will blow or not. Can someone please help me?

TL;DR Is this the right fuse, or explain to me how I can use I²t to determine what is the right fuse value? (see image for visualization).

setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjRjW.jpg
datasheet fuse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6JlS.jpg (2 pics)

Comment: You can reduce inrush with an ICL repeat question

Comment: In EE we use SI prefixes such as k for kilo, m for milli, etc., rather than exponent / scientific notation.

Comment: The fuse is to protect the wire, not the load.

Comment: The inrush current value you gave is irrelevant.  That's what the power supply can provide maximum (and only for a very short time).   What it will actually deliver is dependent on your LOAD.  Think about this.. If you had no load connected, it wouldn't output any current, right?   So obviously the load is ultimately the controlling thing.   Some loads have high inrush currents, some do not.  What is the nature of the load you are driving?  (i.e. what is it?)

Comment: @KyleB that's odd. I also was thinking that before I asked someone on Reddit. He said: "The inrush current does not depend on the load current.

The inrush current is the current that charges the line side capacitor. Load current on the DC side does not enter into this because the converter is not converting until after the inrush event is over." So now I am confused. The load is an APC Smartslot expansion chassis.

Comment: 6mA is not \$6^{-3}\$A it is \$6\times10^{-3}\$A.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I used "e" but this site made automatic formulas for it and changed it to the wrong notation. Nevertheless, thanks for the correction and I changed it.

Comment: @Jelle Understand now what the load is... That's why I asked  ;)  Yes, something like that card will have an inrush while the caps charge up.  However, you can be sure it's not going to be 35A.... The resistance of the contacts and traces, and even the internal resistance of the caps under question, will prevent that.   You could have been asking about ANYTHING, like a light bulb, a motor, etc... All very different things from a digital circuit board.

Comment: Anyhow, IMO this challenge is far easier than you are making it.   30mA is your 'nominal' load, and you do need to worry (a little) about the inrush, so  just use a fuse that's well above 30mA and is rated as a "time delay" (or 'slow blow') fuse.  Maybe 100mA or 150mA.     The 'time delay' characteristic is usually marked on the fuse as a "T".  The delay is specifically meant to prevent nuisance blowing due to inrush.